# JSON.NET invokes interface property getter even when `ObjectCreationHandling` is set to `Replace`

Tags: json.net

Given the following serializable class structure:

```
public class Foo
{
    private IBar bar;
    public IBar Bar
    {
        get 
        { 
            if(this.bar == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("bar must be set before it is read"); 
            return this.bar;
        }
        set 
        { 
            if(value == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("value");
            this.bar = value;
        }
    }
}
public interface IBar { }
public class Bar : IBar { }
```

And the following custom JsonConverter to ensure `IBar` gets converted to `Bar`:

```
public class BarConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(IBar);
    }
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var jobject = JObject.Load(reader);
        return jobject.ToObject(typeof(Bar), serializer);
    }
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("This should not be invoked.");
    }
}
```

The following code fails because JSON.NET tries to invoke the `Foo.Bar` getter when that property has never been set:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ObjectCreationHandling = ObjectCreationHandling.Replace,
    Converters = { new BarConverter() }
};
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>("{Bar: {}}", settings);
```

My understanding is that `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` should prevent the getter from being invoked. Indeed, if I change the `Bar` property's type to be the concrete `Bar` class instead of the `IBar` interface, then `ObjectCreationHandling.Replace` works just fine.

Is this a defect in JSON.NET, or is there a reason that a property declared as an interface should ignore the `ObjectCreationHandling` value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not the fact that the property is declared as an interface that the `ObjectCreationHandling` setting is ignored; it is because a converter is in play for that property that it is ignored.  When you change the property declaration from interface `IBar` to concrete `Bar`, the `CanConvert()` method in your converter returns `false` because the `objectType` is not equal to `IBar`.  This removes your converter from the equation, so Json.Net takes the "normal" code path which considers the `ObjectCreationHandling` setting and  does not call the getter.  If you change the implementation of `CanConvert()` to
`return typeof(IBar).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);`
then you will see that the getter is called regardless of whether the property is declared as `IBar` or `Bar`.

I believe that this behavior is by design, and not a defect.  The contract of the `ReadJson` method requires that the existing value of the object be passed in (via the `existingValue` parameter) so that the converter can decide what to do with it, if anything.  There's no way for Json.Net to determine what the existing value is without calling the getter, so it has to call it.

If I were you I would change the `Bar` getter implementation not to throw an exception if you can.  Per [Microsoft recommendations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229006.aspx) it is considered bad practice to throw an exception within a property getter:

> **AVOID** throwing exceptions from property getters.
>
> Property getters should be simple operations and should not have any preconditions. If a getter can throw an exception, it should probably be redesigned to be a method. Notice that this rule does not apply to indexers, where we do expect exceptions as a result of validating the arguments.

Comment: Excellent sleuthing. Thank you.

Comment: Glad I could help.